# self.scope['user'] always shows me the same user, Django Channels

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am a beginner in `Django Channels` and I try to make a chat app. I think everything works fine, but the problem is that the message is not send to both of users connected to the room, just to the one of theme. I think the problem is inside `consumer.py` in `user = self.scope['user']` becuase if I print the `user` it shows me every time only the first user that wrote something. So if I have two users: `user1` and `user2` and if `user2` write something as first, it `user = self.scope['user']` will always give me the second user. I am using Redis by WSL2.

Based on this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8&list=LL&index=3&ab_channel=CodingEntrepreneurs

an example console log if one of the user send something:

```
receive {'type': 'websocket.receive', 'text': '{"message":"abc"}'}
message {'type': 'chat_message', 'text': '{"message": "abc", "username": "test"}'}
message {'type': 'chat_message', 'text': '{"message": "abc", "username": "test"}'}
```

templates/thread.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Thread for {% if user != object.first %}{{ object.first }}{% else %}{{ object.second }}{% endif %}</h3>
<ul id='chat-items'>
{% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}

<li>{{ chat.message }} via {{ chat.user }}</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

<form id='form' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' id='myUsername' value='{{ user.username }}'/>
{{form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
</form>

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reconnecting-websocket/1.0.0/reconnecting-websocket.js'></script>
<script>
// websocket scripts
var loc = window.location
var formData = $("#form")
var msgInput = $("#id_message")
var chatHolder = $("#chat-items")
var me = $('#myUsername').val()

var wsStart = 'ws://' 
if(loc.protocol == 'https:') {
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("message", e)
    var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
    chatHolder.append("<li>" + chatDataMsg.message + " via " + chatDataMsg.username + "</li>")
}

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("open", e)
    formData.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var msgText = msgInput.val()

        var finalData = {
            'message': msgText
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
        formData[0].reset()
    })
}

socket.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("erro", e)
}

socket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("close", e)
}

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", InboxView.as_view()),
    re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", ThreadView.as_view()),
]
```

routing.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$", ChatConsumer())
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

consumer.py:

```
import json
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from .models import Thread


class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)

        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        me = self.scope['user']
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(me, other_user)
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("receive", event)
        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg = loaded_dict_data.get('message')

            user = self.scope['user']
            username = 'default'
            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.username

            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username
            }

            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text": json.dumps(myResponse)
                }
            )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        print('message', event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event['text']
        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]
```

Comment: Your logs look correct. In `websocket_receive` you generate a response `myResponse` that contains the username of the user that sent the message and then you send that response to all connected users via the group

Comment: It should work as you say, but it doesn't send the message to all connected users (to two users), but just to the single one of thme (and the one of them displays two same messages).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django-channels : ChatConsumer is sending message to only one user instead of sending it to both users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247174/django-channels-chatconsumer-is-sending-message-to-only-one-user-instead-of-se)